# How to handle redirection with spring security and primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-security

I'd like to have a link/button which redirects me to another page depending on **the user role** and a certain String **value** (of a variable returned by a controller method).

So a user can't access that page **unless he has the appropriate role AND the appropriate value.**

I'd like to know how to handle this redirection with primefaces and spring security (I'm using primefaces 4 and spring security 3.2.3.)

Thank you.

NB: It's not a post login redirection

---

**EDIT :**

I had already implemented the authentication mechanism... **My problem is further**... After the user has been authenticated and redirected to a welcome view, I want to make him access to a certain other view depending on **1)** his role and **2)** a String value (He **clicks a button** and it redirect him to **the appropriate UI**)... That's that I want to do with primefaces and spring security

Comment: did you thought about making a verification process composed from two steps ,the verst step based on String Value on your controllers , the second steps handled by spring security threw Role_USER

Comment: @oussama.elhadri can you give more details please on how to implement these 2 steps

Comment: those String value are static or dynamic ?

Comment: @oussama.elhadri it's dynamic... actually it's a value from a datatable row

Answer (score 0):

this post here explain how to handle redirection after the user login [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login)

you need to create your own AuthenticationSuccessHandler and inject it using.

```
<form-login login-page='/login.html'
            authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<logout/>
```

...

```
public class MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler{..}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I had already implemented the authentication mechanism... My problem is further... After the user has been authenticated and redirected to a welcome view, I want to make him access to a certain other view depending on 1)his role 2)a String value.. (i.e: he click a button and it redirect him to the appropriate UI)... That's that I want to do with primefaces and spring security

Comment: you still specify the authentication handling ! It's not my problem actually... I have **already** done the redirection after the login. My problem is: **After login**, the user is redirected to a page where he can see all his related "modules". I want him, when he click on a module (Primefaces button), to see its details, he is redirected to the module details page... BUT I want to check BEFORE the redirection, if he has the permission to see this page = if he has THE specific role for THAT specific module..

Comment: if this button click is related to function you could use annontation @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')") to handle authorisation,or i think you should create a custom filter.